# Order of Maven+Surefire+Testng - BeforeClass, BeforeTest, Test, Test, AfterTest, AfterClass

Tags: maven, testng, surefire

I expected the following output:

```
Running TestSuite
[DEBUG] beforeClass
[DEBUG] beforeTest
[DEBUG] test
[DEBUG] afterTest
[DEBUG] beforeTest
[DEBUG] test
[DEBUG] afterTest
[DEBUG] afterClass
```

But instead, this actually happens. Notice 2 problems: BeforeClass runs *after* BeforeTest. Second, Before/AfterTest runs *once*.

```
Running TestSuite
[DEBUG] beforeTest
[DEBUG] beforeClass
[DEBUG] test
[DEBUG] test
[DEBUG] afterClass
[DEBUG] afterTest
```

Here's the code.

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class TestNgAnnoTest {
   @BeforeClass
   public void beforeClass(){
      System.out.println("beforeClass");
   }
   @BeforeTest
   public void beforeTest(){
      System.out.println("beforeTest");
   }
   @Test
   public void test1(){
      System.out.println("test");
   }
   @Test
   public void test2(){
      System.out.println("test");
   }
   @AfterTest
   public void afterTest(){
      System.out.println("afterTest");

   }
   @AfterClass
   public void afterClass(){
      System.out.println("afterClass");
   }
}
```

For anyone curious about tool versions:
java macosx/1.6.0_22, mvn: 2.2.1, surefire 2.6, testng 5.14.2

Answer (score 5):

Stupid me. Confused After/BeforeTest with After/BeforeMethod.

```
[DEBUG] beforeClass
[DEBUG] beforeMethod
[DEBUG] test
[DEBUG] afterMethod
[DEBUG] beforeMethod
[DEBUG] test
[DEBUG] afterMethod
[DEBUG] afterClass
```

Replacing After/BeforeTest produced the correct exec ordering.

```
    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass(){
        log.debug("beforeClass");
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(){
        log.debug("beforeMethod");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        log.debug("test");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        log.debug("test");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod(){
        log.debug("afterMethod");

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass(){
        log.debug("afterClass");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Correct. @BeforeTest/@AfterTest wrap a  tag, not a test method.